# HP dl380 g6 raid0

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Im planning on buying a HP dl380 g6, but I'm new to the raid thing. Could I do a raid0 with 7X146gb, and use all the 7 drives.

The raid controller is a p410i.

Comment: Sure you can. It's not a good idea, though.

Comment: What is your goal? First link of a search gives you all answer you need about this RAID controller: https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01677092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure as long as the data on the RAID volume doesn’t matter. A 7 disk RAID 0 should be configurable on that RAID controller.

If you’re unsure about RAID and the appropriate RAID level for your use, make sure you read this: [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them/339214#339214)

I believe the p410i supports 0, 1, 10, 5, and 6 But it’s been a while, so I may be wrong there.